# Break out of loop when no channel in a select group receives signal in specified time

Tags: go, concurrency, timeout, channel

How do I break out of the idiomatic Go for loop containing select statement, if and only if I receive no signals on any of the channels my select statement is listening to, for a particular period of time.

Let me enhance the question with an example.

#### Setup:

1. Lets say that i have a channel `var listenCh <-chan string` that I am listening to.
2. Let us assume that some other go routine(not in our control) sends different strings on this channel.
3. I do some processing with the given string and then listen for the next string on the `listenCh`.

#### Requirement:

I want to wait 10 seconds maximum(precision not critical), between two successive signals on the `listenCh`, before I shut down my operations(break out of for loop permanently).

#### Code Stub:

```
func doingSomething(listenCh <-chan string) {
  var mystr string
  for {
    select {
      case mystr <-listenCh:
        //dosomething
      case /*more than 10 seconds since last signal on listenCh*/:
        return
    }
  }
}
```

How would I achieve my requirement in the most efficient manner possible.

The usual quit channel technique with `time.After(time.Duration)` seems to not reset after one loop and hence the whole program closes in 10 seconds even if there is a continuous stream of values.

I find variants of the question(but not what I want) on SO, but none that I saw answers my particular use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Foreword:** Using `time.Timer` is the recommended way, use of `time.After()` here is only for demonstration and reasoning. Please use the 2nd approach.

---

#### Using `time.After()` (not recommended for this)

If you put [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) in the case branch, that will "reset" in each iteration, because that will return you a new channel each time, so that works:

```
func doingSomething(listenCh <-chan string) {
    for {
        select {
        case mystr := <-listenCh:
            log.Println("Received", mystr)
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            log.Println("Timeout")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

(I used 1 second timeout for testability on the Go Playground.)

We can test it like:

```
ch := make(chan string)
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        ch <- fmt.Sprint(i)
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}()
doingSomething(ch)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1MkpTQO3GdZ)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Received 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Received 1
2009/11/10 23:00:01 Received 2
2009/11/10 23:00:02 Timeout
```

#### Using `time.Timer` (recommended solution)

If there is a high rate receiving from the channel, this might be a bit of wasting resources, as a new timer is created and used under the hood by `time.After()`, which doesn't magically stop and get garbage collected immediately when it's not needed anymore in case you receive a value from the channel before timeout.

A more resource-friendly solution would be to create a [`time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) before the loop, and reset it if a value is received before a timeout.

This is how it would look like:

```
func doingSomething(listenCh <-chan string) {
    d := 1 * time.Second
    t := time.NewTimer(d)
    for {
        select {
        case mystr := <-listenCh:
            log.Println("Received", mystr)
            if !t.Stop() {
                <-t.C
            }
            t.Reset(d)
        case <-t.C:
            log.Println("Timeout")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Testing and output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xudkt2lSpr_d).

Comment: "The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector until the timer fires." With frequent messages on `listenCh`, isn't there going to be a lot of uncollected timer garbage?

Comment: @peterSO Yes, was working on addressing that. See edited answer.

Comment: @icza Would you consider reordering your answers. I think the answer with the `time.Timer` is the correct answer while the `time.After` one will likely result in an explosion of go routines.

Comment: @poy You're right, but talking about `time.After()` first is logical. But I did put a note to the beginning of the answer, and stressed which solution is recommended.

Comment: @poy, [timers don't create goroutines](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/go-timers/).

Comment: @Peter You're right. I was thinking of `time.AfterFunc`. However rapidly building a growing list of timers that are preparing to fire is a poor idea.